# How to prevent variable overwriting when using it in for loop to paint objects

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to create HTML objects using JS native script. I hae a function, that paints some text and I want to optimize it.

When I use it, it must write some text in HTML using loop to make several different iterations but instead I found out that new loop does not make a new object in HTML but remakes previous.

```
    paintPrimary: (id, alias, country, date, content) => {
        let primaryArray = ['Alias', 'Country', 'Date', 'Description'];
        console.log(primaryArray);
        const $primary = document.createElement('div');
        $primary.className = 'teamHeaders';

        for (let primaryCounter = 0; primaryCounter < primaryArray.length; primaryCounter ++) {
            $primary.innerHTML = primaryArray[primaryCounter];
            document.getElementById(id).appendChild($primary);
        }
    }
```

I tried to use constructors but had no success. Was thinking of making a new variable for every iteration everytime, but I dont know how to do such a thing and havent found any info

Comment: Because you are not creating the element inside the loop. You are creating one element before the loop and then you are changing it inside the loop. Create the element inside the loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Create the element `div` inside the loop. In your case you are creating the `div` only once, so it is overwriting

```js
paintPrimary: (id, alias, country, date, content) => {
  let primaryArray = ['Alias', 'Country', 'Date', 'Description'];
  for (let primaryCounter = 0; primaryCounter < primaryArray.length; primaryCounter++) {
    // changed here
    const $primary = document.createElement('div'); 
    $primary.className = 'teamHeaders';
    $primary.innerHTML = primaryArray[primaryCounter];
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild($primary);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
paintPrimary: (id, alias, country, date, content) => {
    let primaryArray = ['Alias', 'Country', 'Date', 'Description'];
    console.log(primaryArray);

    for (let primaryCounter = 0; primaryCounter < primaryArray.length; primaryCounter++) {
        const $primary = document.createElement('div');
        $primary.className = 'teamHeaders';
        $primary.innerHTML = primaryArray[primaryCounter];
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild($primary);
    }
}
```

When you call `paintPrimary` multiple times, it will create separate sets of div elements for each call, rather than overwriting the previous content.